# I am somehow installing Python without the standard library

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to install Python (just assumed use the latest version, 3.5.1) on Red Hat Linux. Somehow the standard library is not getting installed, I also can't use pip. I'm pretty new to Linux, so it's entirely possible I'm making a really stupid mistake.

My installation has been (what I think is standard)

```
./configure
make
make install
```

which runs fine. Then I was using a symbolic link to have 'python' point to the new install, something similar to

```
ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python
```

which seemed to work, because entering

```
python --version
```

returned 3.5.1 correctly.

So what am I doing wrong? Why does my install seem to lack the standard library?

To clarify the reason that I suspect that the standard library isn't installed, what happened is that I tried to use pip and discovered it wasn't installed, so attempting to install it using the get-pip.py file I received a message that zlib not available.

Comment: You can't use the package manager? Like, `yum install python`?

Comment: What exactly is it that's not working for you?

Comment: Have you checked your install path? What's your `$PYTHONPATH`, `$PYTHONHOME` and `sys.prefix` look like?

Comment: Your link names seem bogus. The file systems usually used with Linux are case-sensitive so `Python` and `python` are not the same thing.

Comment: typing    yum install python    gives a SyntaxError. I am running Red Hat 6.7 btw

Comment: @BenI that's because you've messed up your python install and yum uses python under the hood.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the  `$PYTHONPATH`, `$PYTHONHOME` and `sys.prefix`

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH`, `echo $PYTHONHOME` `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.prefix)'` in your terminal.

Comment: `sys.prefix` gives /usr/local . `echo $PYTHONPATH` and `echo $PYTHONHOME` return nothing

Comment: Please don't install things globally (like in `/usr/bin`) without understanding WTF you're doing. You **will** screw up your system, *guaranteed*. Install in your `$HOME`, make `~/bin`, and add it to the front of your `$PATH`. From your lack of mention of `sudo`, you're probably logged in as `root`, too. Make a regular user and *use it*.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a missing zlib.

It would be nice to check if you have the *other* standard library modules, such as `random`, `collections` etc. installed.

When building python from source, you need to specifically configure and compile python with `zlib`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250530/1220089) explains how to do it, quoting from it:

> - Install the appropriate Zlib-dev package. For example on Ubuntu it is called zlib1g-dev. This will provide the zlib.h include file.
> - After compiling your python sources run the configure script: ./configure –with-zlib=/usr/include
> - Now make and make install should work.

[Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344970/building-python-from-source-with-zlib-support)

***As a side note***, over-writing your standard python2 install with python3 is not the smartest of moves on a RHEL family operating system. It will probably break yum at the very least and bork your box in the worst case.